# Trimming/Pruning Solr index (imported from MySQL which is trimmed daily)

Tags: mysql, solr, lucene

I am running Solr which gets its data imported from MySQL every minute using DIH. Right now MySQL has its tables trimmed/pruned every day.

**Problem:** How should I prune Solr's index? Do I do a full-import, or delete the older documents followed by a commit?

Currently about 20,000 new documents are added to Solr everyday, which is expected to increase to 100,000 new documents per day. So this is the number of documents that will be trimmed from MySQL and Solr each day. There will be about 200,000 documents in the index at any time, expected to increase to 1,000,000.

Comment: Did you ever find any more information on this? I am looking at doing something similar.